# Why is this private class member out of scope at the point where I try to call it?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, mobx

I want to be able to call "setUser", but it's out of scope for some reason.  This is in a MobX store that I've created.  I'm sure it's something I'm doing fundamentally wrong, but I don't know what it is.  Here's the code:

```
private setUser = (user: UserType) => {
        this.userRegistry.set(user.Username, user);
    }

    loadUsersFromPoolGroups = () => {
        this.loadingInitial = true;
        
        try {
            var congitoidentityserviceprovider = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider();
            const USER_POOL_ID = 'us-east-2_kWOEamV6i';

            var params = {
                UserPoolId: USER_POOL_ID
            }

            congitoidentityserviceprovider.listGroups(params, function(err, data) {
                if (err) console.log(err, err.stack);
                else {
                    data.Groups.forEach(group => {
                        var params = {
                            GroupName: group.GroupName,
                            UserPoolId: USER_POOL_ID
                        }

                        congitoidentityserviceprovider.listUsersInGroup(params, function(err1, data1) {
                            if (err1) console.log(err1, err1.stack);
                            else {
                                data1.Users.forEach((user) => {
                                    this.setUser(user);
                                })
                            }
                        })
                    })
                }
            });
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('error loading users from pool groups', error)
        }
    }
```

I'm doing a similar thing in a different store with no issues.

```
private setSubmittal = (submittal: Submittal) => {
        this.submittalRegistry.set(submittal.submittalId, submittal);
    }

    loadSubmittals = async () => {
        this.loadingInitial = true;
        try {
            const submittals = await agent.Submittals.list();
            submittals.data.forEach((submittal: Submittal) => {
                this.setSubmittal(submittal);
            })
            this.setLoadingInitial(false);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            this.setLoadingInitial(false);
        }
    }
```

I expected to be able to call setUser and it won't let me.

Comment: Change your `function (err1, data1) {` to an arrow function.

Comment: Same with `function(err, data) {`

Comment: That worked beautifully.  Thank you!  Obviously I'm a novice with JS and React so thank you for taking the time to help me.

Comment: @jswift please next time include the error message

Comment: Will do.  I just noticed the setUser method was out of scope so went with that.  It was a TypeError of some sort.  Thanks again.